Uniqueness of center manifold in the analysis of a generic fold point.
I am currently trying to understand the paper "Extending geometric singular perturbation theory to generic fold points" by Krupa and Szmolyan. There the following system of ODEs comes up.
\begin{align}
&x_1' = -1 + x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_1x_1 + \mathcal{O}(r_1) \\
&r_1' = \frac{1}{2}r_1\varepsilon_1(-1 + \mathcal{O}(r_1)) \\
&\varepsilon_1' = \frac{3}{2}(1 + \mathcal{O}(r_1)).
\end{align}
I am interested in the point $p_a = (-1,0,0)$. Here the linearization gives eigenvalues -2,0,0.
Reducing this system to the invariant plane $r_1 = 0$ yields
\begin{align}
&x_1' = -1 + x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_1x_1 \\
&\varepsilon_1' = \frac{3}{2}\varepsilon_1^2
\end{align}
with eigenvalues $-2,0$ and the eigenvector corresponding to the $0$ being $(-1,4)$
The authors now claim the existence of a center manifold $N_{a,1}$ at this point, which I understand. But they also claim this center manifold $N_{a,1}$ to be unique for $r_3 = 0$ and $\varepsilon_1 > 0$, which I dont understand. I could not find much in the literature about uniqueness of center manifolds. The authors just note it and say that it follows from standard center manifold theory while referencing the book of Carr and the book of Guggenheimer and Holmes in which I could not find why this need be unique. I was told that there might be some reasoning using analyticity of the center manifolds, but I could not compute an explicit solution and find its analyticity.
In case it helps with the reasoning, they claim that the center manifold coming from the point $p_r = (1,0,0)$ where the nonzero eigenvalue is 2 with the same eigenvector is not unique for $r_1 = 0$ and $\varepsilon_1 > 0$.
My guess is that it might have something to do with the stability. An explanation or a further reference on center manifold theory involving their uniqueness would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: Is the reasoning here, that since $\varepsilon_1$ is increasing, for the center manifold to approach $p_a$ we can only consider the case $t \rightarrow - \infty$. As the second eigenvalue is negative we have an attracting behaviour and hence a repelling behaviour when approaching $- \infty$. Now my thought was that due to this repelling behaviour, we can only have one solution approaching the point tangent to the eigenvector. Is this the correct reasoning?
Thank you!
